# Python: subprocess Popen hangs

Tags: python, subprocess

I am having an issue with the subprocess module, specifically with the Popen class. I am learning sockets in python and have two servers communicating via sockets. The logic is as below
         Server A sends list of git dirs to Server B.
         Server B iterates over the list of git dirs and returns SHA hash for every dir to the requesting server A. However, the problem arises when there is a failure. Code:

```
  Server B : Python version : 2.4.3 

  while 1:
       data=conn.recv(1024)
       if not data: break
       #DEBUG
       #print "data:",data
       proc=subprocess.Popen(["git","--git-dir",'/var/git/temp/'+data,"log","-1","--all","--pretty=format:\"%H\""],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
       # Ignore failure and move on
       # continue or pass do not seem to work \
       # neither does exception handling
       if proc.wait() !=0 : pass
       sha_hash,err=proc.communicate()
       print sha_hash
       conn.send(sha_hash)

conn.close()
```

Now when there is a failure such as default revision of a git project is set to HEAD, the subprocess call fails and it prints return code of 128 but it just hangs there. I am not able to figure out a way to return back to my processing of remaining directories and I have to kill the process. I tried using poll() as well but did not work. Any suggestions are appreciated.

EDIT1:

```
    Removing wait 

    while 1:
       data=conn.recv(1024)
       if not data: break
       #DEBUG
       #print "data:",data
       proc=subprocess.Popen(["git","--git-dir",'/var/git/temp/'+data,"log","-1","--all","--pretty=format:\"%H\""],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
       # Ignore failure and move on
       # continue or pass do not seem to work \
       # neither does exception handling
       ## removed wait and just using communicate ##
       sha_hash,err=proc.communicate()
       print sha_hash
       conn.send(sha_hash)

conn.close()
```

Comment: You `wait` and `communicate`. Both wait for the process to complete so if the process waits for input, the latter is never reached.

Comment: I see what you mean. I added the wait part later because I am not sure how to bypass the situation. So even if i remove the wait part and just use communicate, it still gives the same result. Updating my code to reflect this change.

Comment: Are you sure you're getting to the process launch? Does conn.recv() get its input? I mean, is it nonblocking?

Comment: Well, it seems to be launching because i get this in the o/p:data: data_test1.git
"5ae510385a9cd0eeaa8bfd3693eb0ec69bee10bf"
data: data_test2.git
"dac785d53e3b580d28cee34501620f0e4b78d243"
data: data_test3.git
"76cc596b25dd9c277b9133812ce65821328323bc"
data: data_test4.git
"ba0dda781bbc0462981da1c021e98a769d25dcc5"
data: data_test5.git
fatal: bad default revision 'HEAD' # this is where it gets stuck

Comment: if you think that `subprocess` is at fault then remove unrelated `conn.recv()`, `conn.send()` e.g., read `data` from a local file and see whether you can reproduce the issue. Or better, create a dummy git repository that triggers the `fatal: bad default revision 'HEAD' ` error and see whether `Popen()` continues to get stuck. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve